# How to do multiple image batch inference on yolov3 model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have deployed the yolov3 object detection model on the TF server. I can successfully do inference on the single image now I want to test server capacity for multiple batch of images but  when I try to pass multiple images I get an error as "Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 6\n\t [[{{node yolov3/yolo_nms/Squeeze}}]]" saved_model signature as follow

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['input'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, -1, -1, 3)
      name: serving_default_input:0
```

when I do inference with a single image of size (1,416,415,3) model accept  and perform inference on it but when I pass a batch of array of  images say for 6 images with shape (6,416,416,3) I get an error as

```
details = "Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 6
[[{{node yolov3/yolo_nms/Squeeze}}]]"
debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1623239327.766680379","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:127.0.0.1:8500","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1061,"grpc_message":"Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 6\n\t [[{{node yolov3/yolo_nms/Squeeze}}]]","grpc_status":3}"
```

> 

code for loading batch of images is as below

```
load_imgs = load_images_from_dir("/content/yolov3-tf2/image_data/",416,6)
print(load_imgs.shape)
(6, 416, 416, 3)
```

code for sending this image batch through gRPC request to tf server is as below

```
request.inputs["input"].CopyFrom(
      tf.make_tensor_proto(
          load_imgs,
          dtype= types_pb2.DT_FLOAT ,
          shape=load_imgs.shape
      )
  )
```

the model description shows it accepts any number batch of images as dimension is declared -1  but when I pass multiple images it throws an error as above. I used model from this code repo [model code source](https://github.com/zzh8829/yolov3-tf2) code for model conversion to saved_model format as below

```
!wget https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3.weights -O data/yolov3.weights
!python convert.py --weights ./data/yolov3.weights --output ./checkpoints/yolov3.tf
!python ./tools/export_tfserving.py --output serving_model/yolov3/1/

!saved_model_cli show --dir serving_model/yolov3/1/ --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default

2021-06-10 19:40:53.843200: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['input'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, -1, -1, 3)
      name: serving_default_input:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
  outputs['yolo_nms'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, -1, 4)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
  outputs['yolo_nms_1'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (1, -1)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:1
  outputs['yolo_nms_2'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_INT64
      shape: (1, -1)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:2
  outputs['yolo_nms_3'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_INT32
      shape: (1)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:3
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

what am I doing wrong?

Can I pass an arbitrary number of images to the model which is trained on different batch size? or is it hardcoded to specific batch size? or am I calling it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

No You are calling it totally wrong way. Any model in general will be have input shape [BATCH_SIZE,FEATURE_SIZE] e.g [8,640,640,3]. So batch of images is independent in yolo. you can use batch concept for inference over images.

Comment: Ok. Why am I getting errors when I try to pass a batch of images then?